# How can urllib2 be used to open a URL as a File object?

Tags: python

The following methods return different objects:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
>> <addinfourl at 148620236 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x8db0b6c>>
```

and

```
open("/home/me/image.png")
>> <open file '/var/www/service/provider/web/test.png', mode 'r' at 0x8da3d88>
```

Is it possible for urlopen to return the same type of object that `open` returns? I do not want it returned as a stream. I guess it is a `File` object

Answer (score 1):

The two are almost the same as a file object. If you see the [official docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), they say that "This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods:"...

So knowing that, you can use similar methods to what you'd use on a file object, such as:

```
myFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/image.png")
myFile.read()
```

For thing like images (it looks like that's what you're talking about), this will print an ugly data-representation of the file. You can write this to a file on disk using something like

```
with open("mySavedPNG.png",'w') as w:
    w.write(myFile.read()) # note that if you have already done myFile.read() you will need to seek back to the start of the file with myFile.seek(0)
```

If you actually want to manage pngs in Python, use something like the [png Module](http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html)